# html5/css/javascript : How to superpose two canvas in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

```js
function drawAll() {
  // Upper zone, 8 grey transparent buttons
  let canvas0 = document.getElementById("layer0");
  canvas0.width = 1000;
  canvas0.height = 100;
  let bandeau = canvas0.getContext("2d");
  bandeau.fillStyle = "rgba(128,128,80,0.3)";

  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    bandeau.beginPath;
    bandeau.arc(50 + 110 * i, 50, 45, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    bandeau.fill();
  }

  // Lower zone, a red rectangle partially under the buttons
  let canvas1 = document.getElementById("layer1");
  canvas1.width = 1000;
  canvas1.height = 1000;
  let dessin = canvas1.getContext("2d");
  dessin.fillStyle = "red";
  dessin.fillRect(30, 50, 800, 200);
  canvas0.style.visibility = "visible";
  canvas1.style.visibility = "visible";
}

drawAll()
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(249, 249, 250);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -10;
}

.scrollable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="layer0" class="scrollable"></canvas>
  <canvas id="layer1" class="fixed"></canvas>
</div>
```

Hello

I'm stuck on a superposition problem of two canvas. Here is a simplified example. Note that in the real application, buttons and drawings are far more complicated and that I want to keep the structure with html5 / css / javascript.

I suppose that I miss something in the css to succeed to have these two canvas superposed, buttons partially covering the red rectangle, but what ?

Thanks if somebody can help.

Comment: Hi, could you check out your snippet and make sure it runs OK and shows something? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see anything on the screen when running this code. The drawings are very simple and should show on the screen. My problem is "why don't they show up"

Comment: I'm not familiar with "snipet". I get an error for "draw function unknown" though it is included in the javascript section. I probably missed something in copying/pasting my code in the three boxes for js/css/html ! Be sure that if I assemble correctly these three pieces of code, be it in a single file or split in three files, I have the same problem of canvases which don't show up.

Comment: I edited and fixed the snippet. You do not need the entire HTML setup, also it is best to call your JS function from the JS block.

Comment: I don't see any mod to the snippet. Is it because I tried to edit it at the same time : I guessed (probably false) that the "draw" function name could be reserved and changed it to "drawAll". Is there a page somewhere to learn how to use this "snippet" tool ?

Comment: I see now the modified snippet code. Thanks. Remains the "blank screen" problem, canvases don't show themselves.

Comment: @JiPe38 have you seen my answer? All you need to do is to make space for the canvases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `<body>` doesn't have any height, which makes the `.container` height of `100%` equally zero.

Absolutely positioned elements do no contribute to their parent's height. As soon as you start giving `.container` an actual height, you can see its content. In the example below, I went for `100vw` and `100vh` for width and height, but since your canvases are 1000px wide, you could also use that or any other value.

---

> An absolutely positioned element no longer exists in the normal document layout flow. Instead, it sits on its own layer separate from everything else.

Source: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning)

---

The other option is to remove `overflow: hidden;` from `.container` and show everything outside of it.

```js
function drawAll() {
  // Upper zone, 8 grey transparent buttons
  let canvas0 = document.getElementById("layer0");
  canvas0.width = 1000;
  canvas0.height = 100;
  let bandeau = canvas0.getContext("2d");
  bandeau.fillStyle = "rgba(128,128,80,0.3)";

  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    bandeau.beginPath;
    bandeau.arc(50 + 110 * i, 50, 45, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    bandeau.fill();
  }

  // Lower zone, a red rectangle partially under the buttons
  let canvas1 = document.getElementById("layer1");
  canvas1.width = 1000;
  canvas1.height = 1000;
  let dessin = canvas1.getContext("2d");
  dessin.fillStyle = "red";
  dessin.fillRect(30, 50, 800, 200);
  canvas0.style.visibility = "visible";
  canvas1.style.visibility = "visible";
}

drawAll()
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(249, 249, 250);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -10;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.scrollable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="layer0" class="scrollable"></canvas>
  <canvas id="layer1" class="fixed"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Yessssss it works. I didn't know these vh and vw units and thought that "%" could do the job. Obviously not. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JiPe38 Cool, glad I could help. I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as "accepted" by clicking on the check mark at the left of it.